# TestNG @BeforeMethod onlyForGroups option removed

Tags: java, testng

I was looking for some way to have some @beforeMethod logic executing only for a group of java unit tests (using TestNG ).
I found on TestNG documentation:

> onlyForGroups:    Only for @BeforeMethod and @AfterMethod. If specified,
> then this setup/teardown method will only be invoked if the
> corresponding test method belongs to one of the listed groups.

Which seems to be what I'm looking for.

But when I try to use it, it's not implemented in @BeforeMethod and @AfterMethod annotations. I couldn't find find any information on the web about it missing.

Maven dependency :

```
         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.14.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrade you version, as you see in [Changes](https://github.com/cbeust/testng/blob/d615583e2d63c809e9cf02357cb5338be24198ab/CHANGES.txt), it was added **after** 6.14.3 version

> Fixed: GITHUB-549 and GITHUB-780: Introduce onlyForGroups attribute for @BeforeMethod and @AfterMethod (Sergei Tachenov)

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
I first thought of upgrading the version. So i tried to change the version to the latest (7.4) but get the same result.
I will try again tomorrow (can't today).

Comment: I don't know  why i did not see it the first time but when going for version 7.4 i do have the property. It was added on version 7.0. 
Anyway, sorry for the inconvenience and thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Notice the version of TestNG used in the dependency.

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>7.4.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
</dependencies>

import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class TestNgBeforeMethodAnnotation {

    @BeforeMethod(onlyForGroups = {"Group1"}, groups = {"Group1"})
    public void setupForGroup1()
    {
        System.out.println("Before Method for Group 1 called");
    }

    @Test(groups = {"Group1"})
    public void testCaseInGroup1()
    {
        System.out.println("testCaseInGroup1");
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering!
I already tried switching to 7.4 but without seeing any difference. Maybe i missed something, I'll try again tomorrow.

Comment: Pay attention to the imports used as well in your code